Selenium break while loop for infinite scroll
I am trying to scrape all the job listings for software engineer intern in LinkedIn. When it reaches the end of the list, the see more jobs button is still present and I am not sure how to implement a While loop and to break the loop when there are no more listings available.
def scrape_linkedin(driver):
    linkedin_url = f'https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/software-engineering-intern-jobs?position=1&pageNum=0'
    driver.get(linkedin_url)
    job_list=[]
    
    for i in range (2):
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(2)
        

        try:
            # Wait for the "Show more" button to be present on the page
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located(
                    (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main-content"]/section[2]/button')
                )
            )
            element.click()

        except Exception:
            # Log a message indicating that the button was not found and we're retrying
            print("Show more button not found, retrying...")
        time.sleep(2)       
        job_titles = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="main-content"]/section[2]/ul/li/div/div[2]/h3'))
        )

        job_companies = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="main-content"]/section[2]/ul/li/div/div[2]/h4'))
        )

    for title, company in zip(job_titles, job_companies):
                job_object = (
                   title.text,
                   company.text
                )
                job_list.append(job_object)

    print(job_list)
    print(len(job_list))
    driver.quit()

scrape_linkedin(driver) 


can you share a screenshot of the page with the "Show more" button visible?
